# Passing a struct to construct an array of Structs

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create an array of structs by creating a function to fetch data from firestore and then passing the three structs fetched to an array of structs. Here is my code:

```
func fetchUsers() {

    var user1: User
    var user2: User
    var user3: User

    docRef = Firestore.firestore().document("users/user1")
    docRef.getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in
        guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else { return }
        let myData = docSnapshot.data()
        let fName = myData!["name"] as? String ?? ""
        let fUsername = myData!["username"] as? String ?? ""
        let fBioText = myData!["bioText"] as? String ?? ""

        let user = User(name: fName, username: fUsername, bioText: fBioText, profileImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mauricioprofileimage"))

        user1 = user
    }

    self.docRef = Firestore.firestore().document("users/user2")
        self.docRef.getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in
        guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else { return }
        let myData = docSnapshot.data()
        let fName = myData!["name"] as? String ?? ""
        let fUsername = myData!["username"] as? String ?? ""
        let fBioText = myData!["bioText"] as? String ?? ""

        let user = User(name: fName, username: fUsername, bioText: fBioText, profileImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "trumpprofileimage"))

        user2 = user
    }

    self.docRef = Firestore.firestore().document("users/user1")
        self.docRef.getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in
        guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else { return }
        let myData = docSnapshot.data()
        let fName = myData!["name"] as? String ?? ""
        let fUsername = myData!["username"] as? String ?? ""
        let fBioText = myData!["bioText"] as? String ?? ""

        let user = User(name: fName, username: fUsername, bioText: fBioText, profileImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "amandaprofileimage"))

        user3 = user
    }

    return [user1, user2, user3]
}

let users: [User] = fetchUsers()
```

The problem I'm getting is that when I try to fill my users array, it says that it doesn't recognize the user1, user2 and user3 that I created in the Fetchfuncion.

Ps: I'm using firestore. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is, either.

Comment: I edited the question in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put each request in a group, and only once all three users have been retrieved, return the array of users. What's happening with your code is that it's returning an array of empty users (or perhaps 1-3 inconsistently), due to the fact that these calls are asynchronous so the data returned from a firebase request isn't guaranteed to exist when the array is returned.

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
make_async_request_1 {
    // Process response
    group.leave()
}

group.enter()
make_async_request_2 {
    // Process response
    group.leave()
}

group.enter()
make_async_request_3 {
    // Process response
    group.leave()
}
group.notify(queue: .main) {
    // This will run after all 3 group.leave() calls are made
}
```

Comment: @MauricioTakashiKiyama its for anything that is asynchronous, I use this a lot :)

Comment: @Jay make_async_request_1 is getting the errors "Use of unresolved identifier "make_async_request_1" and 2 and 3 as well.

Comment: @MauricioTakashiKiyama that's because those are placeholders, they aren't literal swift code. Those would be the functions you want to execute asynchronously.

Comment: @MauricioTakashiKiyama did the answer work? If so please mark my answer as correct